# How can i trim the NMEA strings in Python (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: raspbian, python

i have a question right now i can get the NMEA string given by the gps antenna every seconds. Now my question is all i want is to get the $GPRMC using infinite while loop in python. Below is the sample output of antenna.

b'$GPGGA,083439.000,1437.9128,N,12100.2349,E,1,08,1.2,21.1,M,39.1,M,,0000*66\r\n'
b'$GPRMC,083439.000,A,1437.9128,N,12100.2349,E,0.47,24.55,140117,,,A*51\r\n'
b'$GPGGA,083440.000,1437.9128,N,12100.2350,E,1,08,1.2,21.0,M,39.1,M,,0000*61\r\n'
b'$GPRMC,083440.000,A,1437.9128,N,12100.2350,E,0.43,24.55,140117,,,A*53\r\n'
b'$GPGGA,083441.000,1437.9127,N,12100.2353,E,1,08,1.2,21.1,M,39.1,M,,0000*6D\r\n'
b'$GPRMC,083441.000,A,1437.9127,N,12100.2353,E,0.29,24.55,140117,,,A*52\r\n'
b'$GPGGA,083442.000,1437.9126,N,12100.2350,E,1,08,1.2,20.9,M,39.1,M,,0000*65\r\n'
b'$GPRMC,083442.000,A,1437.9126,N,12100.2350,E,0.29,24.55,140117,,,A*53\r\n'
b'$GPGGA,083443.000,1437.9123,N,12100.2348,E,1,08,1.2,20.9,M,39.1,M,,0000*68\r\n'
b'$GPRMC,083443.000,A,1437.9123,N,12100.2348,E,0.71,24.55,140117,,,A*53\r\n'
b'$GPGGA,083444.000,1437.9123,N,12100.2351,E,1,08,1.2,21.0,M,39.1,M,,0000*6F\r\n'
b'$GPRMC,083444.000,A,1437.9123,N,12100.2351,E,0.41,24.55,140117,,,A*5F\r\n'
b'$GPGGA,083445.000,1437.9122,N,12100.2354,E,1,08,1.2,21.1,M,39.1,M,,0000*6B\r\n'
b'$GPRMC,083445.000,A,1437.9122,N,12100.2354,E,0.49,24.55,140117,,,A*52\r\n'
b'$GPGGA,083446.000,1437.9122,N,12100.2360,E,1,08,1.2,21.2,M,39.1,M,,0000*6C\r\n'
b'$GPRMC,083446.000,A,1437.9122,N,12100.2360,E,0.75,24.55,140117,,,A*59\r\n'
b'$GPGGA,083447.000,1437.9121,N,12100.2366,E,1,08,1.2,21.4,M,39.1,M,,0000*6E\r\n'
b'$GPRMC,083447.000,A,1437.9121,N,12100.2366,E,0.85,24.55,140117,,,A*52\r\n'
b'$GPGGA,083448.000,1437.9118,N,12100.2371,E,1,08,1.2,21.6,M,39.1,M,,0000*6F\r\n'
b'$GPRMC,083448.000,A,1437.9118,N,12100.2371,E,0.85,24.55,140117,,,A*51\r\n'

Comment: try something like this: if you have each line in a variable called data then you can do

sub = data[9:19]
to get the numeric value from that field

Comment: @SteveRobillard I would avoid slices here, you get such a nice and well behaving separator `,` why not use that? But then again I don't think that's much Pi specific either.

Comment: @Ghanima first and simplest idea

Comment: @SteveRobillard I was just wondering if NMEA string parts are of guaranteed and definite length.

Comment: @Ghanima IIRC they are, but the answer is a better solution  and why I only posted a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have said loop to fetch those strings and you only want the GPRMC and not GPGGA bit of it. Then, in python3, something like

```
s = [long string goes here]
parts = bytes.decode(s).split(',')
if parts[0] == '$GPRMC':
    print(parts[1]) #or whatever you want to do with it.
    asFloat = float(parts[1]) # convert to a float
```

would get you said string / numeric.

Comment: thankis Mr @tobyd it works in me on what i really want to get :)